# Exception when adding new method in a working Service using gRPC-Web and protobuf-net

Tags: asp.net-core, protobuf-net, grpc-web, blazor-webassembly, protobuf-net.grpc

I am getting the following exception:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: The type initializer for 'DefaultProxyCache`1' threw an exception. System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'DefaultProxyCache`1' threw an exception. ---> System.ArgumentException: Invalid generic arguments
> Parameter name: typeArguments
> at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod_impl(System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo,System.Type[])
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod (System.Type[] methodInstantiation) <0x342def8 + 0x000d6> in :0
> at ProtoBuf.Grpc.Internal.ContractOperation.TryGetClientHelper () [0x0001b] in /*/src/protobuf-net.Grpc/Internal/ContractOperation.cs:291
> at ProtoBuf.Grpc.Internal.ProxyEmitter.EmitFactory[TService] (ProtoBuf.Grpc.Configuration.BinderConfiguration binderConfig) [0x00477] in /*/src/protobuf-net.Grpc/Internal/ProxyEmitter.cs:238
> at ProtoBuf.Grpc.Internal.ProxyEmitter.CreateFactory[TService] (ProtoBuf.Grpc.Configuration.BinderConfiguration binderConfig) [0x0006d] in /*/src/protobuf-net.Grpc/Internal/ProxyEmitter.cs:123
> at ProtoBuf.Grpc.Configuration.ClientFactory+DefaultProxyCache`1[TService]..cctor () [0x00000] in /*/src/protobuf-net.Grpc/Configuration/ClientFactory.cs:81

My project uses gRPC-Web, Blazor web assembly and protobuf-net

This is my service contract:

```
[ServiceContract(Name = "Services.Customer")]
public interface ICustomerService
{       
    ValueTask<Customer> CreateCustomer(Customer customerDTO);

    ValueTask<CustomerResultSet> GetCustomers();
}
```

The implementation is:

```
public class CustomerService : ICustomerService
{
    private readonly CustomerUseCases customerLogic;

    public CustomerService(CustomerUseCases customerLogic)
    {
        this.customerLogic = customerLogic;
    }

    public async ValueTask<Customer> CreateCustomer(Customer customerDTO)
    {
        var result = await customerLogic.CreateCustomer(customerDTO);
      
        return customerDTO;
    }

    public async ValueTask<CustomerResultSet> GetCustomers()
    {
        CustomerResultSet result = new CustomerResultSet { Customers = await customerLogic.GetCustomer() };
        return result;
    }
}
```

As for the Datacontracts:

```
[DataContract]
public class CustomerResultSet
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public IEnumerable<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

And,

```
[DataContract]
public partial class Customer
{   
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]        
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 2)]        
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
}
```

Before I was returning a List of customers in the service but I realize I needed a class to model the message in order to protobuf-net be able to serialize that is why CustomerResultSet. Still, it is not working.
Any help much appreciated

Comment: looking now; sorry, I didn't notice this one right away (too many emails!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is... odd. [I can't repro it here](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net.Grpc/commit/db6cf1fdd2e7fc1f0f11a83bb54adec8c13c640b), so I'm guessing it is something specific to Blazor. I've checked what the code does in the "regular" frameworks, and *at least for me* it seems to do the right things - using `UnaryValueTaskAsync<Customer, Customer>()` and `UnaryValueTaskAsync<Empty, CustomerResultSet>()`, which is what I would expect. I've improved the exception handling in that code path, to at least give us a clue what it is trying to do, so my suggestion is:

- update to `protobuf-net.Grpc` version >= 1.0.119 (I'll get it deployed as soon as CI finishes)
- retry, and let me know exactly what it says *now*

Alternatively, if you have a minimal repro *including the blazor bits* on, say, a GitHub repo, I can happily take a look there.

(tip: I try to keep an eye on both Stack Overflow and GitHub, but GitHub is probably more appropriate for this kind of question - I'd happily say that this is a bug, so: https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net.Grpc/issues)

Comment: @Mark-Gravell thank you very much for your kind help.

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: Error obtaining client-helper 'UnaryValueTaskAsync' (from: 'System.Int32', to: 'Domain.Aggregates.ValueObjects.CustomerResultSet'): Invalid generic arguments
Parameter name: typeArguments ---> System.ArgumentException: Invalid generic arguments
Parameter name: typeArguments
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod_impl in .. /_/src/protobuf-net.Grpc/Internal/ContractOperation.cs:294

Comment: that is the error I get after updating. I will post this issue in github

Comment: @paburgos are you sure the service method isn't taking `int` as a parameter? if so: that isn't supported currently (it is on the backlog) - you *must* send a DTO as the query, i.e. some class `Whatever` that *has* an `int` property (as a data-member, etc)

Comment: @paburgos what I need to do is write an analyzer that'll spot this at compile-time...

Comment: Updated my code to receive a reference type DTO and now is working! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem.

System.InvalidOperationException: Error obtaining client-helper 'UnaryValueTaskAsync' (from: 'System.Guid', to: 'Test.DTO.OpResult'): Invalid generic arguments

My entire ServiceContract on that service stopped working. This happened after I added

ValueTask ChangeCompany(Guid companyGuid);

I changed it to

ValueTask ChangeCompany(string companyGuid);

And that got it working again. The error was a bit confusing since i wasn't using ChangeCompany, but like a said, not calls were working.